# Identify duplicated paragraphs (boilerplate) within several email documents

Tags: python, r, nlp, boilerplate

I have started to learn text mining and natural language processing using R and Python. Recently, I was trying to perform some basics tasks such as: (1) the most frequent terms used within a set of documents (email documents) and (2) clustering. The "problem" comes with some repetitive paragraphs, such as disclaimers, signatures on emails, etc; because they are adding some noise to my results.... Is there a way to identify boilerplate or repetitive paragraphs within the set of documents? In order to remove them during the preprocessing tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measuring the similarity of documents is a huge topic, and an active area of research. There are many ways of identifying *boilerplate*, none of them perfect.

But check out the `wydyr` package functions.  Break documents into paragraph-size sections (or smaller.)  Use `pairwise_count` and `pairwise_cor` to get similarity measures between, e.g. the opening and closing sections of documents.

Also, get a copy of *Text Mining with R* by Silge and Robinson; pay attention to Chapter 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot David, I got it!!